# Proof that this product is strictly positive

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, products, infinite-product

Let $\alpha\in [0,1)$. I would like to prove that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that

$$\prod_{i=0}^{+\infty}(1-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^i)>c>0$$.

I tried writing it in the exponential form and after using the Taylor expansion, in the following way:
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=0}^{+\infty}(1-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^i)= \prod_{i=0}^{+\infty}e^{\log(1-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^i)}=\prod_{i=0}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^i-\frac{1}{8}\alpha^{2i}-\frac{1}{24}\alpha^{3i}-\cdots}
\end{align}
But I couldn't succeed. Has someone any idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think you mean to include $\alpha=1$ in the range of validity.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I modified the question! Thank you!

Comment: For $0 \leqslant x \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$ we have $\log (1 - x) \geqslant -2x$.

Comment: Tank you! I could solve with your suggestion!

Comment: @DanielFischer: I was slow in completing my answer. Your comment says it all (+1)